# Programmatically enter cmd.exe application parameter using C#

Tags: c#, cmd

I am trying to create application that will execute my commands from cmd.exe, but I am not sure how to pass additional parameter (password) from user in command line. How I can do that programmatically?

```
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();

        using (StreamWriter sw = process.StandardInput)
        {
            if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
            {
                sw.WriteLine("/c " + command); // run application
                sw.WriteLine("/c mypassword"); // enter first parameter in application
            }
        }
```

Now it's executing like:

- /c myapplication
- 'Hello in myapplication, please enter password:'
- ... (probably stoping myapplication)
- /c mypassword
- 'Unknown command 'mypassword'

Answer (score 1):

[add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments(v=vs.110).aspx) `startInfo.Arguments = arguments` its just a string.  this is just an example with 7za:

```
string arguments = "-mx3 -m0=LZMA2";
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
//startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; //hides the window
startInfo.FileName = sevenZip;
startInfo.Arguments = arguments;
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: And what I should do if application in cmd ask me something to do - and I have to input something additional manual?

Comment: yes if your application is going to prompt for input your going to have to do that manually.    (removing the ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; )

Comment: you should be able to do that with RedirectStandardInput https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the Arguments property to ProcessStartInfo object.. 
Code below works like charm....

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "http://www.google.com";
var process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

[ProcessStartInfo.Arguments - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments(v=vs.110).aspx)